# Writing over a white table (superimpose writing)

Tags: tables, overlays, csvsimple

I'm trying to put the number of rows of a csv file into a latex document, without actually putting the table into the last document.

I've tried the tag package, and putting the table in another latex document with the "\thenumberofrows" between tags. However, when I use "\ExecuteMetaData[file.tex]{tag}" in the real document, it doesn't work and just gives 0 because the table is not in the real document.

So, I need to have an "invisible" table in my real document, that I can take the number of rows from that one. I tried putting the table writing white, but this takes up space in the document. If I can put text over this white table, then it wouldn't be a problem.

If anyone can help me with putting an 'invisible table' on latex, that would be very much appreciated!

Val

Comment: Can  you post a sample compilable document that shows what you're trying to do.  What do you mean by an invisible table? Do you just need to know how many rows an external CSV file has, and then use that number in the LaTeX document?

Comment: If you only want the number  of rows of a particular CSV file, that's easy to do with `csvsimple`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can count lines in a file by opening and reading it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\countlines}{om}
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
  \ior_open:Nn \valerie_countlines_stream { #2 }
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \valerie_countlines_stream
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
   }
  \ior_close:N \valerie_countlines_stream
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \int_eval:n { \l_tmpa_int }
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx #1 { \int_eval:n { \l_tmpa_int } }
   }
 }
\ior_new:N \valerie_countlines_stream
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This very document has \countlines{\jobname.tex} lines.

\countlines[\thisfile]{\jobname.tex}

The number can be stored in \verb|\thisfile|: \thisfile

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `datatool`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
x,y,z,t
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb{test}{\jobname.csv}

\begin{document}

\DTLrowcount{test}

\end{document}
```

This will print 2, because the first line is, by default, considered headers. If you load the file with

```
\DTLloaddb[noheader]{test}{\jobname.csv}
```

you'd get 3.

You can also do

```
\edef\thisfile{\DTLrowcount{test}}
```

and the macro `\thisfile` will expand to the same number.

Comment: Couldn't wait, I see.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily count lines with `csvsimple`.  You just need to use a `\csvreader` command  that does nothing with the row contents:

```
\csvreader{<file>}{}{}
```

If you want to include first line of the file in the count, you can add `no head` to the `\csvreader` command.

```
\csvreader[no head]{<file>}{}{}
```

The number of rows processed is stored in the counter `csvrow` which can be printed with `\thecsvrow`.  Here's a complete example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
ColA,ColB,ColC
A1,B1,C1
A2,B2,C2
A3,B3,C3
A4,B4,C4
A5,B5,C5
A6,B6,C6
A7,B7,C7
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname B.csv}
ColA,ColB,ColC
A1,B1,C1
A2,B2,C2
A3,B3,C3
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{\jobname.csv}

\csvreader{\jobname.csv}{}{}

This CSV file has \thecsvrow\ rows.
\bigskip

\csvautotabular{\jobname B.csv}

\csvreader[no head]{\jobname B.csv}{}{}

This CSV file has \thecsvrow\ rows (header included).

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 1):

The `readarray` package can import and count data from a file.  Here I read it as a record array (ignore any columns).  The row count can sometimes be 1 larger than you wish, if the file ends with a blank line.  So I did a quick `\if` test to screen out that case.

The package can also read in 2-D and 3-D array data, and store it in indexed structures.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
x,y,z,t
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\begin{document}
\readrecordarray{\jobname.csv}\mydata
Records in file: 
\if\relax\mydata[\mydataROWS]\relax\the\numexpr\mydataROWS-1\else\mydataROWS\fi
\end{document}
```

[image]

To give a fuller example of its array-reading capabilities:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
a,b,cCc,d
1,2,3,4
x,y,z3po ,t
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\begin{document}
\obeylines
\readarraysepchar{,}
\readdef{\jobname.csv}\mydef
\readarray*\mydef\mydata[-,\ncols]
Rows, columns read: \mydataROWS, \mydataCOLS\par
making a total of \mydataCELLS{} cells.\par
cell[3,2] is \mydata[3,2]\par
Here is the arraydump of mydata: \arraydump\mydata
Bounds checking\par
no error checking on cell [5,1]: \mydata[5,1]\par
\checkbounds
checkbounds error checking on cell [5,1]: \mydata[5,1]\par
\hypercheckbounds
hyper-checkbounds error checking on cell [5,1]: \mydata[5,1]\par
Log file extract:
\begin{verbatim}
readarray: bounds checking ON
readarray Warning: \mydata[5,1]  out of bounds.
readarray: bounds hyperchecking ON
readarray Warning: \mydata[5,1]  out of bounds:
ROW=5 exceeds bounds(=3) for mydata.
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]